# Rails/Devise changing min length of username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

Rails 3.0
Authlogic 2.1.6

Using username (not email) for authentication.

Authlogic requires username to be at least 3 characters.

How does one convince Authologic to allow a 2 character username?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just looked at the codebase of Devise 1.1.5 and 1.1.3. I did not find the code that enforces a length requirement on username (e.g. validates_length_of). If you find the code that enforces this requirement, please share it. Then I (or someone else) might be able to help with a fix.

Comment: Sorry, my first post said "devise" but for this application I'm using Authlogic (I have a terrible time keeping devise and authlogic straight, from now on it's only devise).

Comment: uggh people still using authlogic in rails 3?

Comment: @AdityaSanghi yes, it's 2013 and we still use it in many projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the authlogic default username length by adding the following code to models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.merge_validates_length_of_login_field_options :within => 4..100
  end

  #....

end
```

This assumes your user model is called `User`